# How should I respond to low quality first post that is already commented

Tags: support, first-post-review

When reviewing first posts I come across low quality posts that I would normally give a comment pointing to MCVE, but a prior reviewer did so first. Should I Skip or "Looks Ok"?

Comment: You can upvote the comment that's already there. If it's a minor issue, you can then say "I'm done"; if it's major, you can close vote or flag.

Comment: @"Benjamin W" If only I could see what was in front of my face. :-(. I hadn't noticed the comment voting controls before.

Comment: how old was the comment? If it was a day old and no sign of activity that can have some bearing on your approach also